# Como validar um campo que depende de outro para ser obrigatório no Symfony?

Tags: validação, symfony

No Laravel existe uma validação `required_if`, nela eu digo que um campo vai ser obrigatório somente se outro campo for informado. Preciso fazer o mesmo tipo de validação utilizando o `FormType` do Symfony mas não encontrei nada na documentação que funcione parecido. Eu consigo validar isso no `Controller` mas queria deixar essa responsabilidade para o meu `FormType` já que todas as outras validações estão nele.

Alguém já fez algo parecido no Symfony que possa me ajudar?

> Versão do Symfony: 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta no stackoverflow em inglês.
Segue o link para a resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206854/conditional-validation-of-fields-based-on-other-field-value-in-symfony2